# DataSet, SqlDataAdapter, Multiple select returns one table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I would like to make one call (containing several SELECT statement) to the database and then databind the results to multiple components.

I'm using a DataSet and SqlDataAdapter to fill tables that are then bound to components.

Problem is the results of the first SELECT statement are put into both tables so I get a "'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property..." error when I try to use the second lot of data on the second component.

Have I misunderstood how this is meant to work?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myString"].ConnectionString);

StringBuilder topicDropDownListSQL = new StringBuilder();
topicDropDownListSQL.Append("SELECT topic.topic_ID, topic.topic_title FROM FPL2012_TOPIC as topic WHERE topic.topic_isEnabled = 1;");
topicDropDownListSQL.Append("SELECT explain.itemExplanationType_ID, explain.itemExplanationType_type FROM FPL2012_ITEM_EXPLANATION_TYPE as explain;");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(topicDropDownListSQL.ToString(), connection);

ds.Tables.Add("Topics");
ds.Tables.Add("ExplainType");

ds.EnforceConstraints = false;

ds.Tables["Topics"].BeginLoadData();
da.Fill(ds.Tables[0]);
ds.Tables["Topics"].EndLoadData();

ds.Tables["ExplainType"].BeginLoadData();
da.Fill(ds.Tables[1]);
ds.Tables["ExplainType"].EndLoadData();

topicDropDownList.DataValueField = "topic_ID";
topicDropDownList.DataTextField = "topic_title";
topicDropDownList.DataSource = ds.Tables["Topics"];
topicDropDownList.DataBind();

explanationTypeDropDownList.DataValueField = "itemExplanationType_ID";
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataTextField = "itemExplanationType_type";
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataSource = ds.Tables["ExplainType"];
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataBind();

connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this acces the tables by there indexes not by there names

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myString"].ConnectionString);

String qry="SELECT topic_ID,topic_title FROM FPL2012_TOPIC WHERE topic_isEnabled = 1; SELECT itemExplanationType_ID, itemExplanationType_type FROM FPL2012_ITEM_EXPLANATION_TYPE ";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, connection);

da.Fill(ds)

topicDropDownList.DataValueField = "topic_ID";
topicDropDownList.DataTextField = "topic_title";
topicDropDownList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
topicDropDownList.DataBind();

explanationTypeDropDownList.DataValueField = "itemExplanationType_ID";
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataTextField = "itemExplanationType_type";
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataBind();

connection.Close();
```

Comment: I tried that but it still results in the same problem. Tables[0] and Tables[1] still only contained the results of the first SELECT STATEMENT.

Comment: I edit the answer debug it with breakpoints and see how many table contained in dataset

Comment: That works! My original code must have been wrong. I wonder which approach (this or datareader) is best practice/most efficient?

Comment: If you have only one table in return then use sqldatareader, it returns a list f records, and like this case use dataset both of your tables are stored in same dataset

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried using a datareader next, didn't expect it to work but it does! I can make multiple select statements and then fill multiple componenets. I'm not marking this as an answer as I still think it would be useful to know how to do it using the dataset.

The new code that worked for me (in case it is useful):

```
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.Append("SELECT topic.topic_ID, topic.topic_title FROM FPL2012_TOPIC as topic WHERE topic.topic_isEnabled = 1;");
sql.Append("SELECT explain.itemExplanationType_ID, explain.itemExplanationType_type FROM FPL2012_ITEM_EXPLANATION_TYPE as explain;");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection);
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

topicDropDownList.DataSource = reader;
topicDropDownList.DataValueField = "topic_ID";
topicDropDownList.DataTextField = "topic_title";
topicDropDownList.DataBind();

reader.NextResult();

explanationTypeDropDownList.DataSource = reader;
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataValueField = "itemExplanationType_ID";
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataTextField = "itemExplanationType_type";
explanationTypeDropDownList.DataBind();

reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```